# REST API and POST request: what data goes in the url and what in the post request?

Tags: python-3.x, api, rest, http-post

I am working on a timesheet webapp. My question is how the url should look like for the backend server. I have seen both provided examples down below used in existing API's. I am very curious about the convention.

Best regards and thanks a lot in advance!

Example:

REST API endpoint: `mycoolwebapp.com/api/timesheet/{user_id}/{date}`
with POST payload:

```
{'hours' : 8, 'operation': 'documentation'}
```

Or:

REST API endpoint: `mycoolwebapp.com/api/timesheet/`
with POST payload:

```
{'user_id': 10, 'date': '2020-08-18', 'hours' : 8, 'operation': 'documentation'}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> what data goes in the url and what in the post request?

A REST API is a kind of facade.  When we are creating a REST API, what we are really doing is providing an interface that acts like an HTTP compliant document store (aka a "web site").

The URI is the key used to retrieve the correct document from the store.  The python analog to consider here is [dictionary](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries).

In the simple case, there are *two* dictionaries that we consider; the first is that being used at the origin server, to keep track of the authoritative copy of each resource.

The second dictionary is the [cache](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7234) used by the client.  Representations of resources are stored using the identifier as the key.

HTTP provides explicit semantics for how cached entries are [invalidated](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7234#section-4.4); that invalidation happens as the result of a successful "unsafe" request.

In other words, one of the things that we are choosing when we decide where to POST a message is which previously cached resource should be invalidated.  Which is the primary document in the cache that will change as a result of successfully handling the message?

What this tells us is that the information we encode into a URI for POST requests should be the same information that we encode into the URI when doing a GET request of the same document.

In contrast: the request body doesn't affect the caches in any way -- part of the point of REST is that all of the information needed by general purpose components is contained within standardized metadata.  No general purpose component needs to parse the message body to understand what is happening in the [transport documents over a network](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aQVSzMV8DWc&t=3m8s) domain.

So you can pretty much do what you like with the message body.

It's perfectly reasonable, for instance, to put all of the information that you need into the message body, with some of that information also duplicated in the URI.

For your specific timesheet example, the question that I would be interested in is what URI do you use to *read* the timesheet?  If we are retrieving the document using something like

```
GET /mycoolwebapp.com/api/timesheet/10/2020-08-18 HTTP/1.1
```

then this would be a perfectly reasonable way to update the server's copy of that document

```
POST /mycoolwebapp.com/api/timesheet/10/2020-08-18 HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json

{'user_id': 10, 'date': '2020-08-18', 'hours' : 8, 'operation': 'documentation'}
```

Comment: "GET /mycoolwebapp.com/api/timesheet/10/2020-08-18 HTTP/1.1"
I am indeed using that specific way to read the timesheet. Thankyou for your comment and very good explanation!

Answer (score 1):

The below one is Preferred as less amount of data is exposed in the browser.

**REST API endpoint:**
mycoolwebapp.com/api/timesheet

**POST payload:**
{'user_id': 10, 'date': '2020-08-18', 'hours' : 8, 'operation': 'documentation'}

Comment: thankyou for your response. I agree with you but user VoiceOfUnreason has a better motivation.